# mist syncing is in discrepancy with node log

Tags: mist, synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp, morden

I am facing a strange syncing related situation for a couple of hour now (screenshot below makes it easiest to understand).

Although my node is in sync with the network as per the node log (downloaded the last block) and what eth.blocknumber returns in the console mode, the mist wallet tells me I am about two hours late and references an old block number. So the wallet cannot really be used.

[image]

Here is the output of a click on MIST's "run test" :
[image]

Do you know how I can fix this please?

(I m on Ropsten)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem went away with the update to 0.8.8.